# URLに条件分岐用のidが複数あり、その二個目以降のidで条件文をテンプレートで設定する場合の方法。

Tags: smarty

以下の様なURLがあり、そのURLをもとにテンプレート上で条件文を作成したいと考えております。URL上のidはcategory_id、pc_idの順番に並ばなければいけない仕様になっております。質問させて頂きたいことは、テンプレートファイル(smarty)上でpc_idの番号によって条件設定をしたい場合どのような設定にすればよろしいでしょうか。

```
Xxxx/products/list.php?category_id=1?pc_id=1
```

試しに以下の設定ですと機能いたしません。List.phpの直後にあるcategory_idだけを認識して、その後にあるpc_idは認識致しません。

```
{if $smarty.get.pc_id == 1}
X
{else}{if $smarty.get.pc_id == 2}
Y
```

以上のように、URL上に条件分岐用のidが複数存在し、二個目以降のidを使ってテンプレートで条件文を作成したい場合、どのように設定すれば宜しいかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

Comment: 通常URLに複数のパラメータを指定するときは `?category_id=1&pc_id=1` といった感じに、パラメータの区切りには ? ではなく & を使いますが、あえて ? を使われているのでしょうか？またcategory_idは認識しているとありますが、pc_idが巻き込まれていませんか？ 例: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DpUU09moSU9FtnNt

Comment: unarist様、ご教授いただきまして、大変感謝いたします。何らかの原因があったと思われますが、とりあえず問題なさそうでございます。大変おさがわせいたしました。